# error in fetching the data from mongodb database with particular string present in name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
const temp = req.query.text;
const result = await User.find({
  name: { $regex: /req.query.text/i },
}).select("name");
console.log(result);
return res.json(200, {
  success: true,
  data: {
    users: result,
  },
});
```

in this in place of req.query.text when in place the text like aa or nn or any other then it work but when i use req.query.text it not work?
tell please how to correct that?

Comment: Could you put the error in the question?

Comment: Try the constructor syntax instead `new RegExp(req.query.text, "i")`